# Cannot Scrapte Youtube with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

I am trying to do a very simple task of scraping Youtube page.
But it keeps returning empty list as the result.

**Target**: Get join date of a youtube channel

**Original link**: [channel page](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxX9wt5FWQUAAz4UrysqK9A/about)

**Code**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.youtube.com/channel/"+"UCxX9wt5FWQUAAz4UrysqK9A"+"/about"
html=requests.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(html.text,"lxml")

channel_name=soup.find_all(name="yt-formatted-string")
print(channel_name)
```

**Result**:

```
[]
```

**Part of source code**:

```
<yt-formatted-string class="style-scope ytd-channel-about-metadata-renderer">
Joined
Feb 25, 2016
</yt-formatted-string>
```

Please guide. Why i cannot get correct answer?
Thanks.

Comment: `requests` does not load dynamic content (it does not run js code) so you will need to use something that emulates a browser like [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for example

Answer (score 0):

You were really close, you just needed to make some minor changes. You do not need Selenium to do this. Below is a snippet that will do what you need. However, I wasn't too sure what particular data you were looking to scrape, so I just went for the main body. Also if you begin to scrape more, try to get in the habit of using headers with requests so that YouTube doesn't block your ip. Good luck!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.youtube.com/channel/"+"UCxX9wt5FWQUAAz4UrysqK9A"+"/about"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
for div in soup.find_all("div", class_="about-description"):
    print(div.text.replace("\n",""))
```

Sorry, upon reviewing your question again it looks like you may have wanted the "joined information". So below is a snippet for that as well.

```
for span in soup.find_all("span", class_="about-stat"):
    print(span.text.replace("\n",""))
```